# Unable to blit from External Texture to EGLSurface in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl, grafika

When i have tried to render texture and transformation matrix to the EGLSurface, no display is seen in the view.

As a follow up of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829552/issue-in-passing-egl-configured-surface-to-native-and-push-the-data) , slightly i have modified  slightly  the code by following grafika/fadden sample code [continuous capture](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java)

Here is my code:

Here is a draw method which runs on RenderThread.

This draw method is getting invoked properly whevener the data is produced at the producer end from Native Code.

```
 public void drawFrame() {

        mOffScreenSurface.makeCurrent();
        mCameraTexture.updateTexImage();
        mCameraTexture.getTransformMatrix(mTmpMatrix);

        mSurfaceWindowUser.makeCurrent();
        mFullFrameBlit.drawFrame(mTextureId, mTmpMatrix);
        mSurfaceWindowUser.swapBuffers();


    }

run method of RenderThread ->

     public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();

            mHandler = new RenderHandler(this);

            mEglCore = new EglCore(null, EglCore.FLAG_RECORDABLE);

            mOffScreenSurface = new OffscreenSurface(mEglCore, 640, 480);

            mOffScreenSurface.makeCurrent();

            mFullFrameBlit = new FullFrameRect(
                    new Texture2dProgram(Texture2dProgram.ProgramType.TEXTURE_EXT));
            mTextureId = mFullFrameBlit.createTextureObject();

            mCameraTexture = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureId);
            mCameraSurface = new Surface (mCameraTexture);   // This surface i am sending to Native Code where i use ANativeWindow reference and copy the data using post method. {producer}

            mCameraTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(new SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
                    Log.d (TAG, "Long breath.. data is pumbed by Native Layer producer..");
                    mHandler.frameReceivedFromProducer();
                }
            });

            mSurfaceWindowUser = new WindowSurface(mEglCore, mSurfaceUser, false);   // this mSurfaceUser is a surface received from MainActivity TextureView.
    }
```

**To confirm if the produce at the native side producing the data, if i pass directly the user surface Without any EGL configurations, the frames are rendered into the screen.**

At the native Level,

```
geometryResult = ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(userNaiveWindow,640, 480, WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBA_8888);
```

To Render the frame i use

```
  ANativeWindow_lock  and ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost() to render directly frame into buffer.
```

I could not able to think what could be wrong and where i have to dig more ?

Thanks fadden for your help.

Comment: You're not actually drawing anything on your OffscreenSurface -- there should be two calls to `drawFrame()`.

Comment: Hi fadden, do you mean surfaceTexture callback should be invoked two times? kindly provide input. i am afraid, i could not understand where to make drawFrame() twice. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, there are two methods with the same name. Your `drawFrame()` method calls `mFullFrameBlit.drawFrame()` for `mSurfaceWindowUser`, drawing the image on the TextureView, but does not call it for `mOffscreenSurface`. Your offscreen surface will never hold anything but transparent black, because you're not drawing anything on it. I'm assuming your native code is using that as the source for pixels. I don't fully understand what you're doing here though, or where things are breaking down.

Comment: Thanks fadden. Between, I see the preview in the user surface.  Very bad of me. I was keeping  another Surfaceview on top of TextureView. :(.